# How do I download and install xuggler?

Tags: java, xuggler

I am a bit confused on how to download xuggler, I went onto the following link to download it:

http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/xuggle/xuggle-xuggler/5.4/

I downloaded xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar and now am a bit confused on where to go from here.

The purpose of me downloading xuggler is so that I can follow this tutorial:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wdW6tUql154

and require the following files xuggle/share/java/jar to be able to follow the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

include **xuggle** jar in Eclipse jar file

http://blog.xuggle.com/2009/01/23/how-to-write-your-first-xuggler-application-in-eclipse/

http://www.xuggle.com/downloads

Comment: Sorry I didnt realise it would be as simple as that.

Comment: never mind , you're welcome anytime :)